# Ubuntu group permission for directories and files

Tags: permissions, filesystem, 17.04, groups

I might be getting this groups thing completely wrong but this is what i was trying to do.

Created new Ubuntu 17.4 desktop installation in virtual box.

When installing added user 'administrator'.

When installed went to terminal and 'useradd' two new users: 'dubac' & 'mali'.

Created their `/home/user dirs` and `sudo chown` them to those users.

```
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:~$ groups
administrator adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare dubac
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:~$ cd ..
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:/home$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrw---- 21 administrator administrator 4096 Svi 29 14:35 administrator
drwxrw----  3 dubac         dubac         4096 Svi 29 13:49 dubac
drwxr-xr-x  2 mali          mali          4096 Svi 29 14:20 mali
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:/home$ cd dubac
bash: cd: dubac: Permission denied
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:/home$
```

I have restarted the virtual pc several times.

Why can't I access the 'dubac' user dir when I (administrator) have a supplementary group dubac on the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions on folder `dubac` are:

```
drwxrw----  3 dubac         dubac         4096 Svi 29 13:49 dubac
```

- dubac user  has permissions `rwx`
- dubac group has permissions `rw`
- other has no permission

In order to `cd` into a directory you need the `x` permission (also known as execution)

Since you aren't the `dubac` user, you need to have the `x` permission on the `group` or `other` sections. But none of them has the `x` permission.

Running `sudo chmod g+x /home/dubac` will add the `x` permission to the `dubac` group and will allow you to `cd` inside `/home/dubac` folder

Comment: That's it. After about 20 videos and 20 pages on linux file permissions i needed you to tell me that execute is needed for switching directories.  Thank you, sir!

Comment: @user1941235 - happy to help :)